# Django: Hierarchy model query

Tags: django, django-orm

Imagine there is a model:

```
class OrgUnit(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('parent'),
        related_name='children',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(_('type'), max_length=55, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

And hierarchy sample:

[image]

It is easy find all stores if one knows cluster id (`cluster_id=1`):

```
stores = OrgUnit.objects.filter(
    type='store',
    parent__parent_id=cluster_id
)
```

It is also easy find cluster by sales department id (`sales_department_id=5`):

```
cluster = OrgUnit.objects.select_related('parent__parent').get(pk=sales_department_id).parent.parent
```

And finally find stores for sales department:

```
cluster_id = OrgUnit.objects.select_related('parent').get(pk=sales_department_id).parent.parent_id
stores = OrgUnit.objects.filter(type='store', parent__parent_id=cluster_id)
```

Getting stores by sales department id will make 2 queries to database. I wonder to know whether it possible to fetch stores by sales department id in one query? If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the hierarchy down again with the `children`, so querying the `ForeignKey` relation in reverse:

```
stores = OrgUnit.objects.filter(
    type='store',
    parent__parent__children__children__pk=sales_department_id
)
```

Here we thus query for `OrgItem`s that have a parent that has a parent for which there is a child for which there is a child with as primary key the `sales_department_id`.